# Does machine code use ascii? What is the difference?

Tags: binary

As the question states it, what is the relationship between both? The representation of number 0, which would be 00110000, is the same to its representation in machine code?

Answer (score 1):

No, machine code itself doesn't use any character encoding. There are no characters in binary, only bits.

A particular *machine* may use ASCII in which case an assembler for it would turn `'0'` into `0x30` but not all machines use ASCII.

For example, the System z mainframes use EBCDIC under z/OS so the assembler there would use that encoding when generating machine code.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. According to a definition I found: "Machine code is the elemental language of computers, consisting of a stream of 0's and 1's". Wouldnt a certain sequence of 0's and 1's represent numbers and other characters just as ASCII does? Maybe I am not getting it right. How would a computer store a number or perform a multiplication for example, in this case?

Comment: @Felipe, yes, but it's not the machine code itself doing this. It works only on numbers. The translation of those numbers into characters on a screen or printer is at a higher level. It's the same as a file - there are no _characters_ in a file, only numbers. At some point those numbers are translated into characters for viewing by people.

Comment: So, you mean if I wanted to store letter 'a' in my computer, this would be translated to binary/machine code to become a 01100001?

Comment: @Felipe, for ASCII, yes. For EBCDIC, it would be 01110000 (from memory).

Comment: "From memory" you mean taken from the computer memory right? As far as I know EBCDIC is much less common though isnt it?

Comment: No, I meant I was remembering the `a` EBCDIC code from my own memory, which may be faulty :-)